# Integer.parseInt throws NumberFormatException?

Tags: android, datepicker

I am using a Datepicker in my application. What I am trying to do is getting the date already set in the text field and showing that on Datepicker control. But I am getting NumberFormatException when I use

```
Integer.parseInt(splittedDate[2])  //i.e the year column.
```

When I see while debugging splittedDate containf three values which are fine. but while parsing year column at last index throws exception. I am unable to understand why is it so. pleasehelp me out of this. Following is the implementation of CreateDialog method for Datepicker.

```
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    if (id == DATE_DIALOG_ID) {
        if (birthDate.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(""))
            return new DatePickerDialog(this, mDateSetListener, mYear,
                    mMonth, mDay);
        else {
            String[] splittedDate = birthDate.getText().toString().split("-");

            try{

                Log.i("Month String", splittedDate[0]);
                mMonth = Integer.parseInt(splittedDate[0]);
                Log.i("Day String", splittedDate[1]);
                mDay = Integer.parseInt(splittedDate[1]);
                Log.i("Year String", splittedDate[0]);
                mYear = Integer.parseInt(splittedDate[2]);

            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Log.e("Number Format Exception Message: ",e.getMessage());
            }

            return new DatePickerDialog(this, mDateSetListener, mYear,
                    mMonth, mDay);

        }

    return null;
}
```

Here is the logCat info:

```
 09-05 16:21:54.722: E/AndroidRuntime(28596): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 09-05 16:21:54.722: E/AndroidRuntime(28596): java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse '1970 ' as integer
 09-05 16:21:54.722: E/AndroidRuntime(28596):   at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:383)
 09-05 16:21:54.722: E/AndroidRuntime(28596):   at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:372)
 09-05 16:21:54.722: E/AndroidRuntime(28596):   at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:332)
 09-05 16:21:54.722: E/AndroidRuntime(28596):   at com.test.project.activity.DetailActivity.onCreateDialog(DetailActivity.java:332)
```

Comment: Could you post the string that causes the exception?

Comment: can you please upload stacktrace

Comment: it's basically 3rd element in splittedDate array...whose value is 1970

Comment: Don't know if it is related, but have you noticed that the third print is `Log.i("Year String", splittedDate[0]);` instead of `Log.i("Year String", splittedDate[2]);`?

Comment: Well, what exactly is the year `String`, typically? A `NumberFormatException` is very self-explanatory and means that the `String` doesn't contain a parsable integer. The characters in the string must all be decimal digits, except that the first character may be an ASCII minus sign.

Comment: @Trevor .. you are right. It is a string for the time being "1970" and to get it set in the picker we need integer values so am trying to get an integer from a string.

Comment: I have added logcat .. please check that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Post the code where you are inserting values in `birthDate` field. Check that there should not be any `blank spaces`. There should be digits only. from the Exception, it seems that `'1970 '` contains a blank space. double check the birthDate field..

Comment: Well it exactly was the case. I added  .trim() to my value it worked just fine.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
Integer.parseInt(splittedDate[2].toString())
```

Comment: u getting error because "1970 " contain white space in it, remove it and then parse it